# How to give 6 buttons which is last 6 months those should change dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need 6 buttons one by one,those buttons are month names from last 6 months to current month,
for instannce

```
November
December
January
February
March
April
```

so if month do change,the buttons should change dynamically like

```
December
January
February
March
April
May
```

Kinldy help me .

Note : For this we can use javascript or jquery or php .

Thanks
Sandeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is this in PHP:

```
$result=array();
for($months=5;$months>=0;$months--){
    if(!$months){
         $month_name = date("F");
    }else{
         $month_name = date("F", strtotime("-$months month"));
    }
    $result[]='<button>'.$month_name.'</button>';
}
echo implode('<br>', $result);
```

Comment: Hi @Pumukel Thanq so much for your response ,but i am not getting current month April ,I need current month also ,for that what i need to do,kindly help me .thanks

Comment: Tnx for clarification, I updated my answer just now

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in php like this:

```
<?php
echo "<button> " . date('F') . "</button>"; 
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
  echo "<button> " . date('F', strtotime("-$i month")) . "</button>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi @Ankur Thanq so much for your response ,but i am not getting current month `April` ,I need current month also ,for that what i need to do,kindly help me .thanks

Comment: @muralasandeep check the answer now. I have included current month also.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in JavaScript

```js
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

const maxDateCnt = 11;

const countFiveMonts = [];

const dateTime = new Date();
let monthCnt = dateTime.getMonth();

let monthCpy = monthCnt;

for(let i = 0;  i < 6; i++){
   let current;

    if(monthCnt > maxDateCnt){
        monthCnt -= 12;
        monthCpy = monthCnt;
         current = monthNames[monthCnt];   
    }else{

        current = monthNames[monthCpy + i];
    }
   countFiveMonts.push(current);
   monthCnt++;
}

console.log(countFiveMonts);
```